# show data in blade from pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I show a pivot table called `community_competition` using a blade file like this:

[image]

But I want to show like this, how ?

| no | name | push up | sit up | back up | squat jump |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Dr Keith Crist | 20 | 10 | 12 | 23 |
| 2. | Jaren Wunsch | 34 | 13 | 24 | 53 |

And here is my blade to show the table:

```html
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">name</th>
        <th scope="col">push up</th>
        <th scope="col">sit up</th>
        <th scope="col">back up</th>
        <th scope="col">squat jump</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @php 
      $no = 1; 
    @endphp
    @foreach ($data as $v)
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ $no++ }}</th>
        <td>{{ $v->community->name}}</td>
        <td>{{ $v->point}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

`CommunityCompetition` model:

```php
public function community()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Community::class);
}

public function competition()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Competition::class);
}
```

`CommunityCompetition` Controller:

```php
public function index()
{
    $data = CommunityCompetition::with(['community', 'competition'])->get();

    return view('cms.rank.index', compact('data'));
}
```

`community` table:

```php
$table->id();
$table->string('name', 100);
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Dr.Keith Crist |
| 2 | Jaren Wunsch |

`competition` table:

```php
$table->id();
$table->string('name', 100);
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | push up |
| 2 | sit up |
| 3 | back up |
| 4 | squat jump |

`community_competition` table:

```php
$table->id();
$table->bigInteger('community_id')->unsigned();
$table->bigInteger('competition_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('point')->nullable();
$table->timestamps();

$table->foreign('community_id')->references('id')->on('communities');
$table->foreign('competition_id')->references('id')->on('competitions');
```

| id | community_id | competition_id | point |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 12 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 | 23 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 | 34 |
| 6 | 2 | 2 | 13 |
| 7 | 2 | 3 | 24 |
| 8 | 2 | 4 | 53 |

Answer (score 0):

Well, your table has 6 columns and you are populating only 3 with this code:

```html
<tr>
    <th scope="row">{{ $no++ }}</th>
    <td>{{ $v->community->name}}</td>
    <td>{{ $v->point}}</td>
</tr>
```

So, you need to add 3 more `td`s to complete the other ones. I have no idea what the names are as your `community_competition` does not store this 3 missing columns.

You should end up with something like this (**bare in mind that you have to use the correct model and attribute**):

```html
<tr>
    <th scope="row">{{ $no++ }}</th>
    <td>{{ $v->community->name}}</td>
    <td>{{ $v->point}}</td>
    <td>{{ $v->sit_up }}</td>
    <td>{{ $v->back_up }}</td>
    <td>{{ $v->squat_jump }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: no bro, the point field is based on each competition,
the back up, sit up, push up, and squat jump is get from competition table

Comment: Explain more what do you mean with that, you have declared a 6 column table and you are only filling 3 columns... if my answer is not what you wanted, then explain better what each column is, as you are not clear

Comment: Oh, I see, you want to show a table with those columns, but you are storing this data in `CommunityCompetition` but you have no way of referencing each one, as each `point` corresponds to one of `sit up` or `back up`, etc., right ? Show us the info from `community` and `competition`.

Comment: yes, I already edit my question and add that information